# VHDL others usage on 2D array

Tags: multidimensional-array, vhdl

assume I have a 2D array type defined like this in a package:

```
type My2DArray_t is array(natural range <>, natural range <>) of std_logic;
```

and elsewhere I declare a signal:

```
signal s_2dSig : My2DArray_t(0 to 7, 11 downto 0);
```

Is there a simple way to default all bits to zero? Something like:

```
signal s_2dSig : My2DArray_t(0 to 7, 11 downto 0) := (others => '0', others => '0');
```

And as a heads up, I am aware that this is simple to do by changing the type to be an array of an array (rather than a 2d array), and normally that's how I would define a multi-dimensional array, but my hands are tied in this instance.

Comment: Not sure if it works, but you may try `:= ((others=> (others=>'0')))`

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.3.3.3 Array aggregates para 5. *An aggregate of an n-dimensional array type, where n is greater than 1, is written as a one-dimensional aggregate in which the index subtype of the aggregate is given by the first index position of the array type, and the expression specified for each element association is an (n–1)-dimensional array or array aggregate, which is called a subaggregate. A string or bit string literal is allowed as a subaggregate in the place of any aggregate of a one-dimensional array of a character type.* xvan is correct and it's legal for an initial value.

Comment: Excellent! It does indeed work. Unfortunately, I'm going to need a rosetta stone to understand the IEEE wording.

Comment: It's called [inculcation](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inculcate). You have to embrace the standard as a whole, it's self referential and fairly complete. You can't readily attempt to translate what you read there to some other referential framework. An array comprised of array type elements isn't a multidimensional array. (Yet note their aggregates can look identical).